# Proving linear independence of orthogonal complement of $W$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Show that $W \cap W^\perp = \{0\}$ and $W + W^\perp = R^n$

I know that $W^\perp$ contains vectors perpendicular to all vectors in $W$, and that means $W$ and $W^\perp$ are linearly independent, but I have no idea where to start the proof... Can somebody give me some idea of the proof sketch? Thank you all in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

For the first one we have

$$v\in W \cap W^\perp \implies v\cdot v=0 \implies v=0$$

For the second one let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ a basis for $W$ then we can extend that to a basis for $R^n$ by $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_r\}$ with $k+r=n$ and we need to show that the last one is a basis for $W^\perp$.

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t really understand the explanation for the first part D: could you elaborate?

Comment: @RaniceTan If we assume $v\in W \cap W^\perp$ then v must be orthogonal to it self and therefore $v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $X$ is a closed subset of $H$.
we want to show that $X+X^{\bot}=H$ and $X \cap X^{\bot}=\emptyset$.
Suppose that $h \in H$ then there is $x \in X$ such that $\Vert h-x\Vert=$$inf${$\Vert h-p\Vert$ :$p \in X$}. ((Because the function $f(p)=||h-p||$ is continuous on $X$ so $f$ achieves $sup ,inf$ in $X$.))
Now Let $x^{\bot}=h-x$,we will show that $x^\bot$$\bot X$.
For each$e\gt0$ we have
$$||x^\bot||^2=<x^\bot,x^\bot>=<h-x,h-x>=||h-x||^2 \leq ||h-(x+ez)||^2=||x^\bot+ez||^2 \leq ||x\bot||^2+||ez||^2-2Re<x^\bot,ez>$$
so we have
$$2Re<x^\bot,z> \leq e||z||^2$$
Since $e$ is arbitrary then $Re<x^\bot,z> \leq 0$ for each $z \in X$.
Since $X$ is linear subspace then $<x^\bot,z>=0$,so $x^\bot\in X^\bot$.

Comment: oh my gosh... thanks so much for the answer haha but I haven’t learnt till that sophisticated in school yet （　´_ゝ`） we have only learnt till eigenvectors

Comment: oh...good.................in this proof it is sufficient that replace $H$ by $R^n$

Comment: If you want I change the proof for you

Comment: it is not just that haha.. Everything else I just completely do not understand at all